# How to pass main website's secured session cookie to web worker and use it there to call APIs

Tags: javascript, angular, security, session-cookies, web-worker

We use a secure session cookie and the back-end set the cookie through the login API. Http requests are cross-origin. I want to use web-workers to do some calculations and call certain APIs. cookies will be lost in web worker API calls despite using `credentials: 'include'`. What can I do if I don't want to pass back API calls to the main thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the web worker **HAS** main thread cookies including secured ones. to use credentials you should mention `credentials: 'include'` in fetch request params as follows:

```
   fetch('https://example.com/profile', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),

      // this line is important:
      credentials: 'include', // include, same-origin or omit ... as your conditions
    
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log('Success:', data);
    })
```